# Want to convert below html into JSON structure

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, json, jsp

**This is my HTML code**

```html
<table id="detailtab" style="" border="1">
  <tbody id="load-attr">
    <tr>
      <td style="padding: 4px">No of bidder participated in SB&nbsp;<input type="number" value="0" max="5" min="0" style="text-align:right">&nbsp;&nbsp;<span>then eliminate</span>&nbsp;<input type="number" value="0" max="5" min="0" style="text-align:right">&nbsp;bidder&nbsp;
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="padding: 4px">No of bidder participated in SB&nbsp;<input type="number" value="0" max="5" min="0" style="text-align:right">&nbsp;&nbsp;<span>then eliminate</span>&nbsp;<input type="number" value="0" max="5" min="0" style="text-align:right">&nbsp;bidder&nbsp;
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="padding: 4px">No of bidder participated in SB&nbsp;<input type="number" value="0" max="5" min="0" style="text-align:right">&nbsp;&nbsp;<span>then eliminate</span>&nbsp;<input type="number" value="0" max="5" min="0" style="text-align:right">&nbsp;bidder&nbsp;
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**I want to convert this html code into below json structure**

```js
{
    "noOfPredicates": 3,
    "predicates": [{
        "elements": [{
            "label": "No of bidder participated in SB",
            "pre": true,
            "value": "",
            "type": "number",
            "options": [],
            "classAttr": "",
            "visible": true,
            "readonly": false
        }, {
            "label": "",
            "pre": true,
            "value": "then eliminate",
            "type": "display",
            "options": [],
            "classAttr": "",
            "visible": true,
            "readonly": false
        }, {
            "label": "bidder",
            "pre": false,
            "value": "",
            "type": "number",
            "options": [],
            "classAttr": "",
            "visible": true,
            "readonly": false
        }]
    }]
}
```

1. `noOfPredicates` is the no of table rows each row has one `td` contains the elements array of objects .
2. pre : true means label should be in front of input type or otherwise after the input type.
3. If type : display that means it should be span.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you, use sets of rules using DOM Elements directly.

```js
const jsonObject = {};

const table = document.querySelector('table');

function parseHtml(element) {
  Object.entries(element.attributes).forEach(attribute => {
    // add desired data to jsonObject structure
  });
  
  element.children.forEach(child => parseHtml(child));
}

parseHtml(table);
```

Here you can see that I created a recursive function that will help you to move toward the accomplishment of your task.

P.S. don't even try to parse it as a string or with Regex, this is hopeless. Just use DOM and if you have a string that is not DOM then convert it from string like this:

```
var div = document.createElement('div');
div.innerHTML = htmlString;
```

Best wishes, Eugene.